# How to interface E-201C pH sensor with raspberry pi through MCP3008

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi, adc

I am trying to measure the pH of liquids using the E-201C Blue Seed Studio pH sensor.
I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/script) of adafruit to connect the sensor to the pi through MCP3008
I also tried another [tutorial](https://iot4beginners.com/analog-inputs-for-raspberry-pi-using-the-mcp3008/) and I get different values.
I am a newbie in interfacing analog devices to raspberry pi and I am confused with pH conversion from voltage. I checked the official wiki page of seed studio and also I found some comments mentioning I should write my own script to interface with raspberry pi. There are a lot of tutorials available for interfacing mcp3008 with pi but there are no tutorials to interface a pH sensor with pi through ADC. I will feel good if anyone gives me a hand on this.

I also want to connect the TDS sensor for now I just connected the pH sensor for the program execution.

[Source 1](https://iot4beginners.com/analog-inputs-for-raspberry-pi-using-the-mcp3008/)

```
# Importing modules
import spidev # To communicate with SPI devices
from time import sleep
import datetime

# To add delay
# Start SPI connection
spi = spidev.SpiDev() # Created an object
spi.open(0,0) 
# Read MCP3008 data
def analogInput(channel):
  spi.max_speed_hz = 1350000
  adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

# Below function will convert data to voltage
def Volts(data):
  volts = (data * 3.3) / float(1023)
  volts = round(volts, 2) # Round off to 2 decimal places
  return volts

while True:
  pH_output = analogInput(0) # Reading from CH0
  pH_volts = Volts(pH_output)
  tds_output = analogInput(1)
  tds_volts = Volts(tds_output)
  print(f"pH : {pH_output} - {pH_volts}, tds : {tds_output} - {tds_volts}")
  sleep(5)
```

Output:

```
pH : 1361129467683753853853498429727072845824 - 4.39074021833469e+36 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 - 1.0976850545836725e+36 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 - 1.0976850545836725e+36 V, tds : 158456325028528675187087900672 - 5.1114943557589895e+26 V
pH : 2722258935367507707706996859454145691648 - 8.78148043666938e+36 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 0 - 0.0 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 680564733841876926926749214863536422912 - 2.195370109167345e+36 V, tds : 19342813113834066795298816 - 6.23961713349486e+22 V
pH : 85070591730234615865843651857942052864 - 2.744212636459181e+35 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 - 1.0976850545836725e+36 V, tds : 2535301200456458802993406410752 - 8.178390969214383e+27 V
pH : 680564733841876926926749214863536422912 - 2.195370109167345e+36 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 2658455991569831745807614120560689152 - 8.575664488934941e+33 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 10633823966279326983230456482242756608 - 3.4302657955739764e+34 V, tds : 4951760157141521099596496896 - 1.5973419861746842e+25 V
pH : 1361129467683753853853498429727072845824 - 4.39074021833469e+36 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 85070591730234615865843651857942052864 - 2.744212636459181e+35 V, tds : 4096 - 13.21 V
pH : 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 - 1.0976850545836725e+36 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
pH : 42535295865117307932921825928971026432 - 1.3721063182295906e+35 V, tds : 0 - 0.0 V
```

[Source 2](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/script)

```
import time
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn
 
# create the spi bus
spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)
 
# create the cs (chip select)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)
 
# create the mcp object
mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
 
# create an analog input channel on pin 0 & pin 1
chan0 = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P0)
chan1 = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P1)
while True:
    print(f"pH : {chan0.value} - {chan0.voltage} V, tds : {chan1.value} - {chan1.voltage} V")
    sleep(5)
```

Output:

```
pH - 42752 -- 2.13 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43968 -- 2.16 V, Tds: 17280 -- 0.0 V
pH - 42176 -- 2.18 V, Tds: 23296 -- 1.13 V
pH - 43392 -- 2.16 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43648 -- 2.19 V, Tds: 18112 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43456 -- 2.2 V, Tds: 22720 -- 1.09 V
pH - 43200 -- 2.14 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.39 V
pH - 43456 -- 2.22 V, Tds: 640 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43072 -- 2.17 V, Tds: 21568 -- 0.09 V
pH - 43648 -- 2.18 V, Tds: 16960 -- 1.17 V
pH - 44160 -- 2.14 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43840 -- 2.18 V, Tds: 17216 -- 0.0 V
pH - 42688 -- 2.18 V, Tds: 23744 -- 1.11 V
pH - 43520 -- 2.18 V, Tds: 1472 -- 0.6 V
pH - 43328 -- 2.22 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.02 V
pH - 43200 -- 2.15 V, Tds: 18240 -- 0.0 V
pH - 42688 -- 2.16 V, Tds: 14592 -- 1.13 V
pH - 44096 -- 2.17 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43968 -- 2.17 V, Tds: 13376 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43200 -- 2.19 V, Tds: 22144 -- 1.09 V
pH - 43264 -- 2.21 V, Tds: 0 -- 0.0 V
pH - 43520 -- 2.17 V, Tds: 17088 -- 0.0 V
pH - 42304 -- 2.19 V, Tds: 13952 -- 1.19 V
```

Comment: Looks like the second is the way to go: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MCP3xxx/, Since the first is deprecated it is out of date.

Comment: Why on the Earth not to use kernel driver https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/adc/mcp320x.c for it? And then use `libiio` (it has Python bindings): https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio